# Dimension of $R^n$ over $R^n$

Tags: vector-spaces

Let $R^n$ forms a vector space over a field $R^n$. What is the dimension of $R^n$ over $R^n$?
It seems me that it will be $n$ as for any $(a,b) \in R^2$ we can write it as:
$(a,b)=(a,0)(1,0)+(0,1)(0,b)$ and here dimension of $R^2$ over $R^2$ seems to be $2$.
However please guide on this if my way of deducting is incorrect or either the answer is incorrect.

Comment: But $\mathbb R^n$ is not a field : what is the inverse of $(1,0) \in \mathbb R^2$?

Comment: You haven't even defined the scalar multiplication! What is $(a,0)(1,0)$?